# Spatial Anchors (Azure mixed reality service) with .Net Framework

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-spatial-anchors

I have cam across the azure mixed reality service so thinking of using it for learning purpose. Can it be used with .net framework? if yes then can anyone please provide me some helpful link for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Developers can build apps with Azure Spatial Anchors using familiar tools and frameworks for their device:

- Unity across HoloLens, iOS, and Android
- Xamarin on iOS and Android
- Swift or Objective-C on iOS
- Java or the Android NDK on Android
- C++/WinRT on HoloLens

For more information, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/spatial-anchor-faq#which-platforms-and-languages-does-azure-spatial-anchors-support-).

***Azure Spatial Anchors*** is a cross-platform developer service with which you can create mixed-reality experiences by using objects that persist their location across devices over time.

This [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices?tabs=azure-portal,VS,Android) helps you to develop and

- Deploy an ***ASP.NET Core web app*** in Azure that you can use to share anchors, and store the anchors in memory for a specified period of time.
- Configure the AzureSpatialAnchorsLocalSharedDemo scene within the Unity sample from our quickstarts to take advantage of the Sharing Anchors web app.
- Deploy and run the anchors to one or more devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because Azure Spatial Anchors (ASA) can use Unity, and Unity uses .NET.

This link describes how to use Unity with ASA:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/unity-overview